# jQuery send values through POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a third party tool. This tool uses a form with the post method to send data to their site. Is there any way that I can mimic this action without using the form tag? I don't know much about jquery post and same domain (this is sending it off to a different domain) so I don't know if there would be an issue with this.

Everything that I've found in my search talks about ajax and returning content after you post but all I want to do is to take the customer to the third party's site after they have submitted the form.

thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use a `<form>`?  You can hide it from view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot send data to a different domain with AJAX. Its not permitted by the browser. As for can you do it without a form element, yes. Just encode the data as it would look in a browser get URL like http://site.com/search?query=I+love+js&perpage=10&page=2

```
datatosend="field1="+value+"&field2="+value2

$.post(url,datatosend,function(data){//do something with data. location.href="new location"}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.  I was able to pass the parameters through the url but was having issues with it. It now looks like it might be issues with the third party.

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

and then you can do a location.replace() when it is completed

```
function replaceDoc()
{
  window.location.replace("http://www.thatsite.com")
}
```

Comment: [Please reconsider suggesting w3schools as a source of information.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: This won't work since it's a cross-domain request and subject to the same-origin policy.

Comment: Thanks Pointy! Had no idea about w3schools.com!

Comment: thanks for the heads up about w3 schools. I'll be sure to avoid linking them in the future and will edit it out of my comment

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Check out this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1078991

also found in the docs

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: This won't work since it's a cross-domain request and subject to the same-origin policy.