# Post Data and Show it in a div using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I've searched through google and all I find a bit complex tutorials on this subject. These are very complex for a newbie like me, so I'm asking a question from a community like here on which I trust.

What's the simplest code I need to post a data inputs to PHP (without refreshing the page) and gets or fetch the result data from PHP file (without refresh) and show this data in a `<div>` Please give me examples.

Thank you and regards

Comment: Why -negative voting? Please understand, I'm newbie and have enough search through google to find out the answer. negative voting wouldn't be counted as help..

Comment: read some javascript[form specific] related tutorials in www.tizag.com (then try codecademy.com)...don't take shortcuts

Comment: the thing is what did you try  ????

Comment: Ok,so you need copy and paste answer. hmm?

Answer (score 3):

On Negative Votes:  take a look at this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

It says this:
What topics can I ask about here?

Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm software tools
- commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are
  unique to software development

---

This is a simple AJAX post with JQuery (since you listed it as a tag).

It posts to `my_page.php` with some data passed (`{ "any_params_to_send" : "in json format" }` that will be received in `$_POST`.  When the response is received, it is put into a div with an ID of `my_div`.

**this is in your main page... index.html**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/where_ever_you_saved_it/jquery.js'></script>

<div id="my_div"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
    url: "my_page.php",
    dataType: "html",
    data: { "any_params_to_send" : "in json format" }
    success: function( response) {
      $('#my_div').html(response);
    } 
  });

});
</script>
```

**this is in my_page.php**

```
<?php
$any_params_to_send = $_POST['any_params_to_send'];  ?>

<div style="border:1px solid black; display:inline-block">

any_params_to_send<br/>

<?php echo $any_params_to_send; ?>

</div>
```

[Other SO Post about this topic...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078909/jquery-send-html-data-through-post)

If you have any problems, feel free to come back and ask!

Comment: How do I call this function?

Comment: Just like that..? Include your jquery as a normal JS script.  Include the function as you would normal JS or JQuery.  Replace what is needed with elements/ids/names specific to your situation.  `my_page.php` would be the PHP page you want to call (and possibly post to) without reloading the main page.  Anything printed on that page will be passed back as a response, and put into `my_div` on a successful completion of the ajax.  There are some good SO links to the right of the page.  If you have a specific problem, please definitely come back to ask a specific question.

Comment: hopefully that can get you started... it's best to fully understand these concepts and what each part does before trying to do something like this.  i just typed that up quickly and didn't test for errors but it should show the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery.

You add it to your page like this...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://exaple.com/jquery.js'></script>
```

Then you learn about jQuery...

http://jquery.com

And implement Ajax...

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: There are no simple answers, but once you understand javascript and jQuery it will be a breeze.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.It gives some basic idea.Please feel free to ask any doubt in this code.

**HTML CODE**

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
var id=$("#id").val();
$.ajax({

                    type:"post",
                    url:"action.php",
                    datatype:"html",
                    cache:false,
                    data:"id="+id,
success:function (response){
      // alert(response);
var data=response;
$("#id").val(" ");
$('#result').html(data); 

}

});
}); 

</script>

</head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
    </form>
    <button  id="btn">Click here/button>
<div id="result"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
 $user_name = "root";
             $password = "root";
               $database = "mydb";
                $server = "localhost";
            $con = mysql_connect($server,$user_name,$password);
           mysql_select_db($database,  $con) ;
$sql="select * from mytable where id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$var=mysql_fetch_row($result)
{
echo '$var['name'];
}
?>
```

**Working of code**

On clicking the `button`,the hidden value in the form is sent to the `action.php` file with out page refreshment.And the response from the `action.php` is collected  in the variable `data` and is displayed in the `div` having id as result.

Comment: You're using `MySQL_` with no sanitized inputs. A sure invitation to a hungry hacker.