# get content from div for form input laravel

Tags: php, laravel, input, ckeditor

I have a form in laravel (not using blade) using CKEditor. I am trying to get the content from it in a `div` called `editorcontents` when I submit the form as it is submitting a blog post (so it needs to have the formatting from that div as well).

I tried assigning a `name` to the div, but no luck. How can I use the `div` just as a `input` field?

```
<div id="editorcontents" name="editorcontents">
</div>

$content = Input::get('editorcontents');
return $content;
```

Comment: Have you try use ajax to post value of div :)

Comment: Trying to stay away from ajax for this one. I can do it with ajax, but I have been told to stick to PHP.

Comment: are you function of CKEditer is running yet ??

Comment: CKEditor is running in JQuery, but for passing stuff I have been told to use PHP, so I want to stick to that.

Comment: can you give me a sample form you try into **http://jsfiddle.net/**

Comment: We need to see your form markup and your editor initialization. Based on your questions and your comments on @HoangHieu answer Im inclined ot think you dont actually have the editor hooked up to anything that can submit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with ajax in jQuery to get html content of **editorcontents** and post this to controller in server :) ... I hope this help

Html

```
<div id="editorcontents" name="editorcontents">
</div>
```

Jquery

```
    var inputValue = $("#editorcontents").html;     
    $.ajax( {
        type : "POST",
        cache : false,
        async : true,
        global : false,
        url : "URL POST DATA",
        data : {
            editorcontents : escape(inputValue),
        }
    } ).done( function ( data )
    {   
        //Handle event send done;
    } )
```

Comment: I am trying to stay away from ajax, but in this case, how long can the string for editorcontents be? Because I originally tried to use it, but it returned nothing if the string was too long

Comment: But when trying to post +- 1000 lines it sent an empty string instead?

Comment: have you setting : **php_value post_max_size**

Comment: I have edited my answer: **editorcontents : escape(inputValue)**

Comment: flow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078909/jquery-send-html-data-through-post

Comment: This works! Obviously I was using something wrong when doing it in AJAX before, Oh well, guess this is the only way to go, so you cant do this in PHP right?

Comment: Yes with **php** is **server language**, **html** and **javascript** is **client language**,  **HTML** on client **php** can't access **get value**, only solution is **send request** from client to server with **javascript** or post data with **form** tag of **html**