# Ajax request JQuery Sending div

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax request to save my mail template in the database. 
However I can't send my div with the ajax request ? I've been looking on the internet for 2 hours now but I couldn't find a solution

the ajax file :

```
function saveEmail(){
    var mail3 = $jQ('templateContent');
    $jQ.ajax({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'ajax/saveMail.php',
        data: {mail2: mail3.html(), test: "test"}
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });

}
```

saveMail.php :

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

exit();
```

The only POST value i get is test  example:

```
    <pre>Array
    (
        [test] => test
    )
    </pre>
```

some usefull info :

```
mail3 = `[prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "templateContent", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]`
```

Comment: Can you show waht is in mail3.html()?

Comment: mail3 is a variable which is on line 2 ( '$jQ('templateContent');' ). It's a basic html template which is being converted to an html element by the .html() function

Comment: Well its undefined atm but mail3 = [prevObject: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1], context: document, selector: "templateContent", jquery: "1.10.2", constructor: function…]  maybe the script fails because its an object?

Comment: Have you tried console logging what `mail3.html()` returns?

Comment: So you are trying to access the html of an array? actually your `mail` thing does not look like a valid structure in javascript. When you do console.log(mail3) what do you get?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078909/jquery-send-html-data-through-post

Comment: i found the problem because of user4328056 his answer.... Such lame mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mail3 = $jQ('templateContent');
```

Should be something like
 `$jQ('.templateContent');` or `$jQ('#templateContent');`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to use `templateContent` as a element `class` or `id`

Try to use `.templateContent` or `#templateContent`.

So you can get content of element by using it's `id` or `class`.

Comment: Yeah such lame mistake, user4328056 said it Thx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The following gives the div's contents in the ajax data call. Note the jquery selector for the div i.e. var dataToSend = $("#templateContent").text();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var dataToSend = $("#templateContent").text();
    alert(dataToSend);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST', 
        url: 'ajax/saveMail.php',
        data: {mail2: dataToSend, test: "test"}
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function that will output "Hello World" in a p element with id="demo".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<div id="templateContent"><span><p>This is supposed to be sent in email!</P><span></div>



</body>
</html>
```